# select rows where value is smaller than the value of a specific row

Tags: sql

Hi I am new to SQL and have a question.
If I want to select all cities from a table of which the population is smaller than NYC (NYC is also in the table).

I can code like this

```
SELECT city FROM table where Population <= (select population from table where name = 'NYC')
```

My question is whether I can write it more concisely like

```
where city.population < NYC.population
```

Comment: i think your first choice is much better and simple :)

Comment: Be aware of the fact that your subquery can return more than one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot write it more concisely that way, because `NYC` is not defined.

You can, however, also write this as a `join`:

```
SELECT t.city 
FROM table t JOIN
     table NYC
     ON t.population < NYC.population AND
        NYC.name = 'NYC';
```

It is not really more concise.  And the difference between the two is really a matter of preference for this particular problem.